# An elementary algebra problem ($10$th grade standard)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find out positive values of $x,y,z$ such that $$xyz=12167$$ and $$\frac{12167+xy}{1+z} + \frac{12167+yz}{1+x} + \frac{12167+xz}{1+y}=1587 $$
At first I made the following substitution: I replaced $$12167=xyz$$ in the equation and I got a simpler form: $$xy+yz+xz=1587$$ How to go further?

Comment: We still have infinite many solutions. Hint for further simplification : $$\frac{1587}{12167}=\frac{xy+yz+xz}{xyz}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$

Comment: Using this equality , you can easily calculate $z$, if you know $x$ and $y$. It remains to find suitable pairs $x,y$. Since $\frac{1587}{12167}=\frac{3}{23}$, the solution $x=y=z=23$ (see also the answer below) can be easily found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the AM-GM inequality
$$xy+yz+xz\geq3\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}=1587$$
Now the AM-GM inequality is an equality only when all numbers are equal $xy=yz=xz\implies x=y=z=23$